# My SSD doesn't have enough space to upgrade to windows 8

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk-space, windows-8-upgrade

I am trying to update my Windows 7 PC to Windows 8 and am having problems with the space on my C: drive.  I have two drives in my computer, one 64 GB SSD (my C:) which has my windows 7 on it and a 1 Tb HDD (my E:) that I use for all my big programs and games.  When I go to upgrade there is only 6 GB of space on my SSD and it needs 20 GB.  Whats the best way to free up space on my C: drive without reinstalling all of my programs? Or can i install Windows onto my E: and somehow transfer it over to my C:?

Answer (score 2):

Why bother upgrading? Programs installed in Windows 7 will probably require a reinstall, so unless you have personal files in C drive, you can format it and do a full reinstall.
As far as I have tried, promotional Windows 8 Pro allows installing even if there is no Windows 7 on the computer, although the promotion requires that you have bought Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Well, C: and E: are different partitions. 
So, **upgrade** means that Win 8 has to come in C: drive. 

And you have 64 GB almost filled up, so sadly you have to uninstall some software and free up space in your SSD.

And as said above. programs installed in Win 7 might need to be reinstalled to work with Win 8

Answer (score 0):

Run Disk Clean up. Uninstall programs that your not using. Otherwise format the C drive and install Windows 8 Fresh on the SSD